# oAuth 2.0 with Titanium

Tags: javascript, oauth, titanium, appcelerator

I am working in Titanium and I need to connect to an oAuth 2.0 server (specifically Quizlet.com: https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization_code_flow/).

I don't know much about oAuth 2.0, but I've heard it's much easier to use than oAuth 1.0 and that I don't need any special frameworks to integrate with it, all I need to do is specify a custom header. Is this possible with Titanium, and if so, how do I achieve it?

Thank you so much and please let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an specific sample for Quizlet and Titanium, but you can take a look at the following oAuth implementations with linkedIn:

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/12521419647/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-linkedin-api-integration

And Foursquare:

https://gist.github.com/885560

It will give you a good starting point